# Comment Blog creating not working symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, crud

Hello i was trying to add comment in blog everything is fine it shows no error but when i click submit nothing happens i mean it doesn't add it in data base i dont know what im missing
this is what i have in controller

```
public function addCommentAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user=$this->getUser();
        if($user==null)
            return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login');
        $add_comment = new CommentaireBlog();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $blog = $em->getRepository(Blog::class)->find($id);
        $add_comment->setBlog($blog);
        $add_comment->setUser($user);
        $add_comment->setDate( new \DateTime());

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($add_comment)

            ->add('contenu', TextareaType::class)
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $add_comment = $form->getData();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($add_comment);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_details'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('blog/details.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'comment' => $add_comment,
            'blog' => $blog,
        ));

    }
```

this is what i have in blog.yml

```
comment_new:
    path:     /{id}/details
    defaults: { _controller: "BlogBundle:Blog:addComment" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
```

and finally this is the twig page

```
<div class="comments-form">
                                <h4 class="comments-title">Leave A Reply</h4>

                                    <!-- .row -->
                                    <form action="{{ path('comment_new', { 'id': blog.id }) }}" method="post" >

                                        <textarea id="form_comment" name="form[comment]" required="required" class="form-control comments-textarea" placeholder="Comments*"></textarea>

                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />


                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Does the blog have a relationship to comments?  If so, somewhere along the line you will need a $blog->addComment($comment) line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just fixed it i displaying the blog with detailsaction and the form is in addcomment action (i checked with using{{form(form)}} and it didnt work so i had to do all the work in details action now it looks like this

```
public function detailsAction(Request $request,Blog $blog){

        $user=$this->getUser();
        if($user==null)
            return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login');
        $add_comment = new CommentaireBlog();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $add_comment->setBlog($blog);
        $add_comment->setUser($user);
        $add_comment->setDate( new \DateTime());

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($add_comment)

            ->add('contenu', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('ajouter',SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $add_comment = $form->getData();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($add_comment);
                $em->flush();

            }
        }

        return $this->render('blog/details.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'comment' => $add_comment,
            'blog' => $blog,
        ));

    }
```

and the twig looks like this :

```
  {{ form_start(form) }}
                                <div class="row form-group">

                                    <div class="col col-md-3"><label class=" form-control-label">Votre Commentaire  </label></div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">{{ form_widget(form.description) }}<small class="form-text text-muted"></small></div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

anyway thanks for for your help <3

Answer (score -1):

There might be a typo:

```
->add('contenu', TextareaType::class) // Should be 'comment'
```

In form you have used :

```
 <textarea id="form_comment" name="form[comment]" required="required" class="form-control comments-textarea" placeholder="Comments*"></textarea>
```

It seems there is mapping error, you can check by just rendering `{{ form(form) }}` in your template

Comment: it says Neither the property "comment" nor one of the methods "getComment()", "comment()", "isComment()", "hasComment()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "BlogBundle\Entity\CommentaireBlog". 
then i think i should change form[comment] to from[contenu] ? right ?

Comment: yes, as expected, mapping error is there. changing form[comment] to from[contenu] would set data to right field in comment object.

Comment: i got the problem not rendering the the form in the template since im im using detailsaction to display and the form is in addcomment action .. so i had to do all the work in detailsaction now its working fine

Comment: Glad it worked out. I don't know why it is down voted, if someone has better explanations better post it! Besides OP  is a new comer and all the edits are welcome. Keep learning!

Comment: i dont know who voted -1 .. i mean yeah like if anyone get an idea should post it not voting negatively on others answers anyway thanks for your time buddy